# Nested Ubuntu very slow

Tags: kvm-virtualization

[image: glance screenshot]ESXi 6.0 on an HP DL585 G7 with 64 GB RAM.
Built a Ubuntu Server 16.04 VM with KVM and other stuff.  20GB hard drive and 8GB RAM.

Built on top of that a Ubuntu Server 16.04 VM: install is extremely slow.
Takes about 2-3 hours to install.  The VM has 2GB RAM and 4GB hard drive.

Any recommendations on what I can do either on esxi or kvm to improve the speed.

Issuing the top command during the install shows only a small amount of swap memory being used.  Perhaps just the fact that swap is being used at all is a red flag.

Comment: Sorry it's a little unclear, you have a server running Ubuntu Server 16.04 and then on top of that another Ubuntu server?

Comment: Yes:  ubuntuServerVM on top of ubuntuServerVM on top of esxi.

Comment: If you run Glances on the first server was is that showing?